# Master - User database: delete records from User databse when deleted from master

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have master DB, which is provided at beginning of an app and user DB which is created later in the life cycle of app. Master DB has some records and this DB cannot be modified.

User DB has some tables which, in turn, has some columns referring to master DB table column values without any trigger or any foreign key constraints. Although there are not links between these columns, if in future a master DB is updated and some records are deleted from master DB, I want to delete rows in user DB referring to rows from master DB.

Now, if any key has been deleted from master DB, how can I reflect it in user DB?

Options:

1. send list of keys deleted on update of master and fire queries on user DB directly - drawback need to keep track of keys deleted in master.
2. Go through all records in user DB and find if any column value (foreign keys) is invalid and deleted.

Which one of the options above should I use?

Comment: There's no easy answer for this. You'll have to do a lot of your own research. This is highly subjective.

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? In MySQL you can use replication to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: sqlite3, slave is partly similar to master. contains few tables that user can actually modify

Comment: Removed the mysql tag.  I suspect that the terms "master" and "slave" (which imply native replication) are not accurate terms for what's being asked, but the question not clear.

Comment: ok got it. Master and slave are exact replicas i suppose in mysql where they are synced over time using replication.